# Github prompts for username and password despite git credentials being stored in .gitconfig

Tags: git, github, token

When I run `git push` on a repository that I own I get prompted for username and password.

```
╭─austin@Austins-MacBook-Pro.local ~/workspace/blah
╰─➤  git push
Username for 'https://github.com/acarrillo2/dotfiles.git': acarrillo2
Password for 'https://acarrillo2@github.com/acarrillo2/dotfiles.git':
```

However when I run `git config --list` I see `github.user` and `github.token` get printed out.

```
...
user.name=Austin Carrillo
user.email=EMAIL@email.com
github.user=acarrillo2
github.token=SUPER_SECRET
```

Looking at the docs for `gh`:
https://cli.github.com/manual/

It appears this should work but just to be sure I also added my token as an environmental variable and it is printed out when I use `printenv`:

```
...
PAGER=less
LESS=-R
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
GH_TOKEN=SUPER_SECRET
```

Is there somewhere else I should be storing these?

Note: I am not using any virtual environments.

I would expect that storing this value in my gitconfig OR my environmental variable would do the trick.

I even tried running the below command and I still get prompted for username and password:

```
╭─austin@laptop ~/workspace/blah
╰─➤  gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
The value of the GH_TOKEN environment variable is being used for authentication.
To have GitHub CLI store credentials instead, first clear the value from the environment.
```

Still get prompted for username and password.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't use your Git config for credentials because that's insecure.  The `gh` command-line tool is not Git and doesn't work the same way.  In fact, Git knows nothing specifically about GitHub and doesn't use `github.*` keys at all.

You'll want to use a credential manager to store your credentials.  If you want to do that using the environment, you can do that [using the technique outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).  Otherwise, you can set `credential.helper` to `manager` on Windows, `osxkeychain` on macOS, or `libsecret` on Linux.  (On Debian and Ubuntu, you must copy `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` and build the credential helper with `make`, then install the binary in your `PATH`.)

Once you've done that, next time you push or pull, you should be prompted for your password.  Enter your username for your username, and the token for the password.  Note that you won't see any echo of characters on the screen.  Then, because you're using a credential helper, Git will save the username and password in the credential store you selected and it should be used automatically in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `git config --global credential.helper`.

If empty, set it to 'manager', and install the latest [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/#git-credential-manager), for [MacOS](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/release/docs/install.md#macos)

The next prompt will then store your credentials (GitHub user account and GitHub token) to said credential manager.

After that, you should not be prompted anymore for your credentials.